# Tabbing from a choicebox to the next element in JavaFX

Tags: focus, javafx-2

How do I get a choicebox in JavaFX to pass focus to the next element when I press tab?

I've tried setting the focus traversable to true but that didn't appear to do anything.

```
cbSoils.setFocusTraversable(true);
```

I've tried setting the key press or release to change focus but it is triggered when I tab TO the choicebox from the previous element.

```
cbSoils.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            // On tab press send the focus to tfAddress
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB){
                tfAddress.requestFocus();
            }
        }
});
```

Anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of FX do you use? I've tested with JavaFX 2.1 b18 and ChoiceBox passes focus on Tab clicks in next code:

```
ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3"));
HBox root = HBoxBuilder.create().children(cb, new Button("next"), new Button("nextnext")).build();
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
stage.show();
```

Comment: I'm using 2.0.3. It must have been fixed in 2.1, along with many [great additions](http://fxexperience.com/2012/03/new-in-javafx-2-1-combobox/). Thanks!